# R Text data scraper loop through dates

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, lapply

I'm doing a little project where there goal is to retrieve data in text format from a website. (http://regsho.finra.org/regsho-Index.html)

The website was nice enough to provide it online but they sorted the data over several days in different links
[image]

I thought about looping through the dates and store the data with the following code:

```
#Download the needed data

my_data <- c()

for (i in 01:13){

my_data <- read.delim(sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%i.txt", i), header=TRUE, sep="|")

}

head(my_data)
```

The problem here is that in line

```
for (i in 01:13){ # The date in the website is 01-02-03 and the loop seems to ommit the 0
```

[image]

I've used the sprintf() method so I can have a variable in a string.

and this line the empty variable my_data always seems to be overwritten by the last data downloaded.

```
my_data <- read.delim(sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%i.txt", i), header=TRUE, sep="|")  
# the empty variable my_data always seems to be overwritten by the last data downloaded.
```

Could somebody reassure me if i'm going in the right direction because i'm starting to doubt myself here

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `01:13` doesn't take into account the "0" but it's the same as `1:13` because it's numeric. You need to have a srtring so try the following Try `stringr::str_pad(1:13, 2, "left", "0")`

Comment: for your second question, try `my_data <- rbind(mydata, read.delim(...) )`

Comment: It doesn't look like there's data for every date, e.g. 2, 3, and 10 are missing. Days are also missing for other months. You might be better off just scraping the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a leading 0 without using an extra package:

```
sprintf("%02d", i)
```

i.e.

```
sprintf("http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol202005%02d.txt", i)
```